# Object Browser not through Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, objectbrowser

**How do I run Object Browser directly from Windows and not from  Visual Studio**?

I'm using Object Browser to study `.Net` classes. It's *much* better than MSDN, because it allows me to **skip** derived members.

For example, when I research [AnimationTimeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.animationtimeline.aspx) I don't have to wade through all the [Timeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.aspx) clutter. I only see what has been added to the derived [AnimationTimeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.animationtimeline.aspx). It's easier to navigate. However, it's a bother to open VS just so that I can use object browser.

Comment: When you say "directly from Windows", do you mean some kind of file system integration? Or a program that is not Visual Studio?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [Telerik JustDecompile](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler.aspx). It's not exactly Visual Studio's object browser, but it's free, and because it decompiles the code, you can see exactly what it's going to do.

You can also find references to a particular class, method, or field.

The available [Extensions](http://www.telerik.com/products/decompiler/extensions.aspx) allow you to [de-obfuscate](https://bitbucket.org/0xd4d/de4dot/) or [modify](http://reflexil.net/) the code in an assembly to which you do not have the source code.

Another option is [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net). However, development seems to have largely ceased in favor of SharpDevelop.